# Remove a recipient from completed envelope in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

When an envelope is completed in docusign an email is sent to all recipients, is there a way to remove one of the recipients from the completed confirmation email?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot modify anything in an envelope once envelope has reached terminal status like Completed, Void, Declined.